# Why does this unlink function not work?

Tags: php, checkbox, unlink

I want the user to be able to delete a file by clicking on a checkbox and submitting the form.
Somewhere in the header:

```
foreach ($_POST ['files'] ['deleteFile'] as $value)
{
    unlink ($value);
    $fileError = '&iexcl;&Eacute;xito!';
}
```

Somewhere in the body:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="files">
<!-- No action attribute was added as the form is processed in the same file -->
<?php
foreach (glob ('files/*.*') as $file)
{
    echo $file . '<input name="deleteFile" type="checkbox" value="' . $file . '">';
}
?>
<input type="submit" value="Confirmar">
</form>
```

Comment: Looks like you need  `unlink('files/'.$value);`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: Nope, `$value` seems to have the complete path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you don't have a key in the `$_POST` super-global called `files`. Assuming you want the values of the selected checkboxes to be added to the `$_POST` array, you should use the following code:

```
<form method="post">
<?php
foreach (glob ('files/*.*') as $file)
{
    echo $file . '<input name="deleteFile[]" type="checkbox" value="' . $file . '">';
}
?>
    <input type="submit" value="Confirmar" />
</form>
```

Note that we call the field `deleteFile[]`. The square brackets tell PHP to handle all fields with the same name as an array. Now, we can use a `foreach()` to loop through each value as follows:

```
foreach ($_POST['deleteFile'] as $value)
{
    unlink ($value); // or you might need unlink('files/'.$value);
    $fileError = '&iexcl;&Eacute;xito!';
}
```

Please be aware that you do not need the `enctype` attribute for this type of request. In addition, PHP is not like JS. The name of the form does not relate to the values in `$_POST`.

Comment: It throws the following error:  Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /public_html/wysiwyg/files.php